# How to get access token through authorization token

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2, openid-connect, openam

I am working on a web app development which needs to have authentication through external authorization system.
I am able to redirect a user to the external authentication server for authentication, once user authenticated and does allow at that time my spring security unable to verify user whether it is authenticated or not.
I am quite confused at security configuration.

Here is my spring security configuration code

```java
@Configuration

@EnableWebSecurity

public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private final String LOGIN_URL = "/login";

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint() {
        return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint(LOGIN_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter(LOGIN_URL);
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ClientContextFilter oAuth2ClientContextFilter() {
        return new OAuth2ClientContextFilter();
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter(), AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter.class)
                .addFilterAfter(openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(), OAuth2ClientContextFilter.class)
                .addFilterAt(openIdConnectAuthenticationFilter(), OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint())
                .and().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(GET, "/test").authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic().and()
                //.addFilterAfter(oAuth2ClientContextFilter(), ExceptionTranslationFilter.class);

                ;
    }
}
```

**OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter**

```java
    public class OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter {

    @Resource
    private OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate;

    protected OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter(String defaultFilterProcessesUrl) {
        super(defaultFilterProcessesUrl);
        setAuthenticationManager(authentication -> authentication); // AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter requires an authentication manager.
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws AuthenticationException, IOException, ServletException 
    {
            System.out.println("checking access token..");
            System.out.println("Response response_type : "+response.getHeader("code"));
            System.out.println("Request response_type : "+request.getHeader("response_type"));

            OAuth2AccessToken accessToken;
            accessToken = restTemplate.getAccessToken();    
    }
}
```

when a user clicked on allow button after authentication, the output is 
[response in the header (code,state,scope)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dshuM.png)

Exception logs:

```java
    checking access token..
Response response_type : null
Request response_type : null
2018-01-04 11:53:48.706 ERROR 16960 --- [nio-8080-exec-6] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception

org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Access token denied.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:142) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:209) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:148) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:121) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.createRequest(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:105) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:655) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.doExecute(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:128) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:620) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.getForEntity(RestTemplate.java:319) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:133) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:121) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213) ~[spring-aop-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy77.getForEntity(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.demo.OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(OpenIDConnectAuthenticationFilter.java:51) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.filter.OAuth2ClientContextFilter.doFilter(OAuth2ClientContextFilter.java:60) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177) ~[spring-security-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar:4.2.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:347) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:263) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:108) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) ~[spring-boot-actuator-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:803) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1459) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_144]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_144]
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.InvalidClientException: Invalid authentication method for accessing this endpoint.
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:80) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.exceptions.OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.deserialize(OAuth2ExceptionJackson2Deserializer.java:33) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3814) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2938) ~[jackson-databind-2.8.10.jar:2.8.10]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readJavaType(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:235) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.json.AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.readInternal(AbstractJackson2HttpMessageConverter.java:215) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.read(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:193) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport$AccessTokenErrorHandler.handleError(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:235) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponse(RestTemplate.java:707) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:660) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:628) ~[spring-web-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.retrieveToken(OAuth2AccessTokenSupport.java:137) ~[spring-security-oauth2-2.0.14.RELEASE.jar:na]
    ... 82 common frames omitted
```

Help me to solve this problem, Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The error message appears to be "Invalid authentication method for accessing this endpoint.". It looks like your Spring client is using an authentication method for the access_token request that hasn't been enabled at the authorization server.

You should have a look at the authorization server settings and make sure that the client authentication method is enabled.

In case you do not have access to the authorization server settings, I would suggest to adjust the client, so that it uses the expected authentication method. This would be done probably by configuring the resource, see [ClientAuthenticationHandler](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/blob/2.0.14.RELEASE/spring-security-oauth2/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/client/token/auth/DefaultClientAuthenticationHandler.java).